# 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, one-hot-encoding, apache-spark-ml

I am using Spark v3.0.0. My dataframe is:

```
indexer.show()
+------+--------+-----+
|row_id|    city|index|
+------+--------+-----+
|     0|New York|  0.0|
|     1|  Moscow|  3.0|
|     2| Beijing|  1.0|
|     3|New York|  0.0|
|     4|   Paris|  2.0|
|     5|   Paris|  2.0|
|     6|New York|  0.0|
|     7| Beijing|  1.0|
+------+--------+-----+
```

Then I want to use One hot encoding of the dataframe's column "index" and getting this error.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="index", outputCol="encoding")
encoder.setDropLast(False)
indexer = encoder.transform(indexer)
```

```
----------------------------------------
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-70bbd67e6679> in <module>
      1 encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="index", outputCol="encoding")
      2 encoder.setDropLast(False)
----> 3 indexer = encoder.transform(indexer)

AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fit it first - before fitting, the attribute does not exist indeed:

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="index", outputCol="encoding")
encoder.setDropLast(False)
ohe = encoder.fit(indexer) # indexer is the existing dataframe, see the question
indexer = ohe.transform(indexer)
```

See the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder.html) in the docs for more details on the usage.

Comment: You use indexer befoer you define it, also link is broken; had same issue

Comment: @DimitriosMistriotis Thanks Δημήτρη. I fixed the link; `indexer` is the already existing dataframe (see the question), so here I am simply overwriting it (nowadays I don't like the practice of overwriting though).

Comment: Thanks, we were following a tutorial :) and fell in a loop. Now we can try again :)